# HTML 5 Progress element freezes on activity

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I want to display an indefinite progress bar while my JavaScript application performs some initialization, e.g. downloading a JSON object using the fetch api. Unfortunately, any activity freezes the progress bar on Firefox 52 64 Bit on Gnome 3.16.4, which may cause my users to reload as they assume the application crashed.

As an MWE I use many `console.log` calls to emulate the initialization, which also results in a blocked progress bar:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body style="width:99%;height:1000px;">
<progress style="width:99%;position:absolute;top:50%;height:20px;"></progress>

<script>
for(i=0;i<100000;i++) {console.log("nop");}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve an unfrozen progress bar during activity?

Comment: you might want [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: When the browser is busy it won't redraw, you need to add a small delay every so often so the progress bar can be repainted, try doing 10 lots of 10000 with a brief timeout between each

Comment: @NickA The MWE is only an emulation for my real use case, which is using the JavaScript fetch API that creates the same problem.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Thanks, I will try Web Workers!

Answer (score 0):

please try this way:

```js
  function print(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      console.log('nop');
      resolve(true);
    });
  }
  
  async function go(){
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++) {
      await print();
    }
  }
  
  go();
```

```html
<progress style="width:100%;height:20px;"></progress>
```

Comment: My Firefox 54 is supposed to support async/await but it still displays some crashes and weird behaviour, I will try it once browser support is better.

Comment: nope doesn't work with chrome 61.... Freezes the entire page, loads all the nops and then the progress bar shows up. Sucks ;(